# Ограничения на конкурс для одного вопроса от одного участника

Tags: поддержка, конкурс

Почему я не могу начать конкурс в этом вопросе?

[Умножение и деление с округлением вверх](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1140487/394322)

Есть ли какие-то ограничения на количество конкурсов от одного участника на один вопрос? Прочитал [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). Единственное возможное ограничение, что я нашёл, следующее:

> Кроме того, если вы начинаете несколько конкурсов для одного вопроса,
> минимальный порог вознаграждения удваивается с каждым последующим
> вознаграждением (50 баллов за первое вознаграждение, 100 - за второе,
> 200 - за третье и так далее).

Насколько я понял, за третий конкурс необходимо минимум 200 репутации, но они у меня есть. Или же имеется в виду, что удвоение идёт относительно предыдущего вознаграждения, т.е. мне необходимо 500x2=1000 репутации? Если так, то стоит изменить описание в справке на более понятное.

Скриншот того, что нет кнопки "начать конкурс":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего там 500, потому что 1000 не существует.

Comment: @Qwertiy придётся ползти до 500, чтобы проверить :)

Answer (score 2):

Там минимум 500 - посмотрел на [этом вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988557/178988):

[image: скриншот]

Comment: А если бы я сразу поставил 250, то в следующий раз надо было бы 500 или 250? Или надо было бы всё равно 100, потому что максимальный лимит не превышен? Стоит обновить/дополнить в справке эту информацию.

Comment: @вася, насколько я понимаю, каждый последующий больше твоего предыдущего (именно твоего, не чужого) в 2 раза, но не больше 500. Но гарантировать не могу.